# How to avoid extra arrows appearing in the Alloy analyser window

Tags: alloy

I have the following specification in Alloy:

```
sig A {}
sig Q{isA: one A}

fact {
    all c1,c2:Q | c1.isA=c2.isA  => c1=c2   // injective mapping
    all a1:A | some c1:Q | c1.isA=a1   //surjective 

}
run {} for 4
```

When I generate an instance of this specification, an extra arrow appears in the demonstration of the instances like `$c1` arrow bellow in the picture. How can I avoid appearing such kind of arrows in instance demonstration? Is there any way to tell instance demonstrator interface not to show them?

[image: attached picture]

Comment: Why Alloy generate this arrow `$c1` at all?! any idea?

Comment: `$c1` is a so called skolem relation. See here: http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/skolem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a bit of search I found the answer:

It is only necessary to define a desired Theme in the demonstration window: click the Theme button in the toolbar and do what ever you'd like! In above specific case remove the tick from the "show as arcs" option of arrow `$c1` in the theme window!

[image: this is how to do it.]